# Поле формы по умолчанию django

Tags: python, django

Делаю регистрацию django. Столкнулся с проблемой, нужно чтоб поле `username` было скрыто и равнялось полю `email`, а не вводилось пользователем.

`views.py`

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from mainApp.forms import Register
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')

# Вариант регистрации на базе класса FormView
class MyRegisterFormView(FormView):
    # Указажем какую форму мы будем использовать для регистрации наших пользователей, в нашем случае
    # это UserCreationForm - стандартный класс Django унаследованный
    form_class = Register

    # Ссылка, на которую будет перенаправляться пользователь в случае успешной регистрации.
    success_url = "/accounts/login/"

    # Шаблон, который будет использоваться при отображении представления.
    template_name = "registration/register.html"
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super(MyRegisterFormView, self).form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        return super(MyRegisterFormView, self).form_invalid(form)
```

`forms.py`

```py
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Register(UserCreationForm):
    def clean_email(self):
    super().clean()
    email = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
    if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
        msg = "Этот адресс уже зарегестрирован."
        self.add_error('email', msg)
    return email

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

Comment: Если использовать представления в виде простых функций, то можно написать любой шаблон с любой разметкой и любой логикой обработки. Не нужно пытаться использовать какой-то подход (class-based-view) во всех ситуациях

Comment: Нужно просто использовать свою модель для пользователя, у которой нет поля username, и всё.

Answer (score 1):

Лучшим вариантом будет использовать свою модель для пользователя, как указали в комментарии, если хочется обойтись тем, что есть сейчас, то я бы сделал так
прятал бы поле e-mail, а не username, так как username обязательно для ввода, а e-mail нет и при проверке данных формы ставил бы email = username. как-то так:

```
class Register(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
        widgets = {
            "email": forms.HiddenInput()   # прячем поле e-mail
        }
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["username"].label = "e-mail" #будем отображать поле на странице как e-mail
    
    def clean_(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        email = self.cleaned_data.get("username")
        if email:
            if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                self.add_error('username', "Этот адрес уже зарегестрирован.")
            else:
                cleaned_data["email"] = email
        return cleaned_data
```